# Syntax error when trying to clear my Symfony project cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

When I try to clear the cache of my Symfony2.8 project, I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     Parse
>   Error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Here is more deParse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/jack/html/fc/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 90

I upgraded my Symfony2.7 to 2.8 yesterday and now I am busy fixing deprecations to get it ready for version 3. I just though about clearing cache now and then, but I just got this error.

I used this command:

`php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @hasumedic I'm running version 5.6

Comment: Sorry, I thought it could be related to [these changes](https://github.com/doctrine/common/commit/71b41aca3f4a2ab881a5bfba635e1babb17313e8) and your PHP version.

Comment: Are you sure your CLI is also running PHP 5.6 ?  What does report "php -v"

Comment: clearing cache will run an issue check on the rest of the application, the problem could be anywhere. Its likely that youll be able to trigger the error via the browser and then use the webdebug toolbar to identify it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

There is likely a problem coming from the PHP version used by the CLI while running the command.

The error is coming from the usage of `[]` as array declaration.
This short syntax has been introduced when PHP released its [5.4 version](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

In a Symfony 2.7 fresh installation, the line that causes your bug looks like :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyDefinition[]
 */
private $definitions = array();
```

In Symfony 2.8 :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyDefinition[]
 */
private $definitions = [];
```

Also the error cannot come from somewhere else.

If your CLI version is really 5.6, you should be able to do run the following from your bash:

```
php -r '$array = []; var_dump($array);'
// output: array(0) {}
```

If you don't get any error, there is something in your project that conflicts with your real PHP version by disabling some features.

Otherwise, you have two options :

- Downgrade Doctrine
- Upgrade PHP

I hope this clarify the real problem.